# MongoDB aggregation with subdocument's 2dsphere index obtained by lookup

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, aggregation-framework

I have two types of collections in MongoDB and their documents look like

#### Shop

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("589601db9635d288491dbe8f"),
    "name" : "shopA",
    ...,
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            126.928059, 
            37.522789
        ]
    }
}
```

#### Menu

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("589601db9635d288491dbe8f"),
    "shopId": ObjectId("589601db9635d288491dbe8f"),  //MenuA belongs to shopA
    "name" : "menuA",
    ...,
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            126.928059, 
            37.522789
        ]
    }
}
```

where "location" is a "2dsphere" index.

I want to get a list of Shops "geoNear" in some distance and also **a list of Menus whose shop is "geoNear" in some distance.**

First query can be made with

```
db.shops.aggregate([
{
  $geoNear: {
    near: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [lng, lat]
    },
    distanceField: "distance",
    maxDistance: 1000,
    spherical: true
  }
}])
```

But how is it possible to make the second query. I have to take a "geoNear" to a subdocument Shop of Menu, so I tried

```
db.menus.aggregate([
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'shops',
    localField: 'shopId',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'shop'
  }
}, {
  $unwind: '$shop'
}, {
  $geoNear: {
     near: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [lng, lat]
    },
    distanceField: "distance",
    maxDistance: 1000,
    spherical: true
  }
}])
```

but it's now working as I expected. It says

> "$geoNear is only valid as the first stage in a pipeline."

Is there any way to accomplish what I want, or is it impossible in MongoDB originally?

Thanks for your kind help in advance.